# Deriving the Probability That at Least One Person is COVID-19 Positive in A Group of Random People That Meet Together for Three Days

Tags: probability

I work in the public sector. To clarify, this scenario is not being used to formulate public policy.

I am trying to calculate the probability that at least one person is COVID-19 positive in a random group of 10 individuals that we need to assemble for three days.

Based on current incidence rates for my area,the probability of at least 1 person being COVID-19 positive in a group of 10 people is 19%. This statistic was retrieved from the website https://covid19risk.biosci.gatech.edu. Criteria is group size 10 with an ascertainment bias of 3. The risk level given in percentage is stated as:

*This map shows the risk level of attending an event, given the event size and location.
The risk level is the estimated chance (0-100%) that at least 1 COVID-19 positive individual will be present at an event in a county, given the size of the event.*

Over the course of the three days, 8 of the 10 members of the group stay the same with 2 members changing. Total group size is consistent. The group meets for 8 hours a day after which they are free to go home. Each group member's infection status **can change** on a daily basis.

I'm inclined to frame the solution as follows:
$$ P(one\,person\, has\, COVID) = 1 - P( no\, one\, has\, COVID)^3 $$

with:

- each day as an independent event
- P(one person has COVID) =.19
- group probability remains unchanged

My main question is, after the first day,does the fact that two people out of 10 change change the group probability from .19 to some other number? My thought is no. Each day, all individuals in the group have an equal chance of infection and that the probability of having COVID-19 for any individual is independent of the status of other individuals.

For reference, here is my calculation based on the scenario:

$ Let\; P(one\,person\, has\, COVID) = .19 $ and $ P( no\, one\, has\, COVID) = .81$

Let n = 3 for the number of days which yields:

$ P( no\, one\, has\, COVID) = (.81)^3 = .5314$

This represents the probability that in a group of 10 people over three separate days, the probability that no one is COVID-19 positive is 53.14%

$P(one\,person\, has\, COVID) = 1 - .5314 = .4685$

My answer is 46.85%

Comment: By one person has COVID, you really mean at least one person has COVID.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a government department with someone with expertise in this line of work, someone with whom you could consult? Doesn't seem right for the public sector to depend on the goodwill of random internet strangers.

Comment: I think more data is needed to answer this question in a rigorous way. Making estimates like this can be considered irresponsible in this real-world situation

Comment: As (perhaps) alluded to by the comment of @Snoop, one of the difficulties is interpreting the statistic-composer's *intent*, as indicated in my answer.  That is, do they mean **at least** 1 in 10, or **exactly** 1 in 10?  I question this, despite your response to N. F. Taussig, because it is unclear whether your interpretation of the website is consistent with the website-composer's intent.

Comment: @GerryMyerson - To be clear, this is not intended to be used for creating public policy, rather, it is an internal exercise we are discussing within our office.  I posted here since I consult on Stack Exchange for solving programming problems.  Frankly, the goodwill of random internet strangers on a targeted forum such as this can be just as effective as consulting with experts.

Comment: @ Snoop - Not using this for public policy.  See my comment above.

Comment: @user2661923 - I edited the question to include the source of the statistic and it's intent.  I also clarified that I am trying to solve for **at least** 1 in 10.

Comment: Based on your last comment, I have just edited my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I disagree with your analysis.  As I see it, the critical factor is the total number of (random) people involved.

As you describe it, since $2$ of the people are replaced, there is an exposure of $(12)$ people.

> Based on current incidence rates for my area,the probability of 1 person being COVID-19 positive in a group of 10 people is 19%.

Let $p = $ the probability that a specific person is COVID-19 positive.

Let $q = 1 - p$.

Then $0.81 = q^{(10)} \implies q \approx 0.979 \implies p \approx (1 - 0.979) = 0.021.$

Then, the probability of at least one person being COVID-19 positive, in a group of $12$ is

$1 - q^{12} \approx 0.223$.

The problem with your approach is that exposure on each of the $3$ days are **not** independent events, since you do not have $10$ different people, on each of the $3$ days.

Admittedly, I am making the assumption that if someone is not COVID-19 positive on day 1, they will also not be COVID-19 positive on day 3.

---

As a more graphic illustration:

which is more dangerous:

- taking a bus ride with the same $10$ people, $3$ days in a row:
- taking a bus ride, 3 days in a row, where there are $10$ different people on each of the $3$ days.

Comment: @user1766490 Please try to clarify: what is your question?

Comment: @user1766490 Assuming that you are living in the USA, one possible source of confusion is the reliability of the statistics.  As of today, there have been about $54$ million reported cases, so the probability of a person being COVID-19 positive in the USA is far greater than $(0.021)$.  My source is [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_pandemic_in_the_United_States).  Of course, apparently most of the $54$ million cases have apparently recovered.  However, it is unclear (at least to me) whether someone who has recovered can still transmit the disease.

Comment: I am making an assumption that there is a chance that a person's infection status **can** change on a daily basis. For the other 16 hours, each person goes about their daily business and risks infection.  Isn't each individual's potential infection status independent from the others? By extension, when the group reconvenes, even with 2 different members, isn't the probability that at least one person out of 10 has COVID the same as the previous day?    This was the thought process that led me to conclude, apparently incorrectly, that each day is independent.

Comment: @user1766490 Realistically, yes, the person's infection status can change on a daily basis.  However, if a person is COVID-19 positive on day 3, then they were probably COVID-19 positive on day 1.  Conversely, if they are not COVID-19 positive on day 1, they are probably not COVID-19 positive on day 3.  So, although a person's infection status can change on a daily basis, their infection status today is probably the same as it was yesterday.  So, your presumption that (in effect) a person's infection status is independent from one day to the next is probably very inaccurate.

Comment: @user2661923 The 54m number is the total number over two years, which is a wildly unrealistic number for the current value. A more realistic approach would be to find some way to estimate the extent to which cases are underreported (which can in principle be inferred from hospitalization/death rates relative to the hospitalization death rates in studies) and then multiply that factor by the number of reported cases over the observed period in which a typical case is infectious. Even in severe cases, that is less than 20 days https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/hcp/duration-isolation.html

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian Good point.